# Bubbelsort + what's displayed

Tags: c#, class, textbox, bubble-sort

I don't get it right when I try to bubbelsort. Also problem with getting the right text displayed in my textbox at the bottom.

I don't get how I will make all my bubblesorted list to get shown in my textbox.
When I press the "Sort" Button my result doesn't gets dispayed correct. It only shows one salesperson, even if I have typed in several in my form and I'm having trouble with getting the text "2 sellers have reached level 3: 100-199 articles" etc. after all the sellers in each level are displayed in order after sold articles.
The result I want to get is:

```
Name          Ssn           District     Pcs
Sara          4503038990    Piteå        173
Michael       6503032345    Malmö        180
2 sellers have reached level 3: 100-199 articles

Peter         3502038964    Boden        202
Emma          7805055673    Luleå        203
2 sellers have reached level 4: over 199 articles
```

Here's my Salesperson class:

```
public class Salesperson
{
    public string Namn = "";
    public string PersNummer ="";
    public string Distrikt = "";
    public int Sold = 0;
    public int Niva()
    {
        if (Sold < 50)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (Sold >= 50 && Sold < 100)
        {
            return 2;
        }
        else if (Sold >= 100 && Sold < 200)
        {
            return 3;
        }
        return 4;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Namn}\t{PersNummer}\t{Distrikt}\t{Sold} \r\n";
    }
}
```

Here's my code in my form.

```
public partial class Inlämning2 : Form
{
    //Lista för att lagra flera salespersoner
    public List<Salesperson> Salespeople = new List<Salesperson>();


    public Inlämning2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public void btnRegistrera_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Läs in uppgifter från formulär
        Salesperson sp = new Salesperson();
        sp.Namn = tbxNamn.Text;
        sp.PersNummer = tbxPersnr.Text;
        sp.Distrikt = tbxDistrikt.Text;
        sp.Sold = int.Parse(tbxSold.Text);

        //Lägg till salesperson i listan
        Salespeople.Add(sp);

        //Visa lista i textruta
        tbxResultat.AppendText (sp.ToString());

        //Töm rutor för ny inmatning
        tbxNamn.Text = "";
        tbxPersnr.Text = "";
        tbxDistrikt.Text = "";
        tbxSold.Text = "";

        //Fokus på ruta 1
        tbxNamn.Focus();
        
    }
    
    public void lblSortera_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Sortera lista baserat på sålda artiklar med bubbelsortera
         void Bubbelsortera(int[] Salespeople)
        {
            int temp;
            //Loopar igenom array med en mindre än sista positionen.
            for (int i = 0; i < Salespeople.Length - (1 + i); i++)
            {
                //i är den aktuella positionen och går inte till sista postionen då den redan är flyttad.
                for (int j = 0; j < Salespeople.Length - (1; j++)
                {
                    //Går igenom listan
                    if (Salespeople[j] > Salespeople[j + 1])
                    {
                        //Om den aktuella är större än nästa, byt plats.
                        temp = Salespeople[j + 1];
                        Salespeople[j + 1] = Salespeople[j];
                        Salespeople[j] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
          Bubbelsortera (Salespeople);
        }

        //Skriv salesperson i ordning och se hur många som nått varje nivå
        int Niva1Count = 0;
        int Niva2Count = 0;
        int Niva3Count = 0;
        int Niva4Count = 0;

        foreach (Salesperson sp in Salespeople)
        {
            string Niva;
            if (sp.Sold < 50)
            {
                Niva = "nivå 1: under 50 artiklar";
                Niva1Count++;
            }
            else if (sp.Sold < 100)
            {
                Niva = "nivå 2: 50-99 artiklar";
                Niva2Count++;
            }
            else if (sp.Sold < 200)
            {
                Niva = "nivå 3: 100-199 artiklar";
                Niva3Count++;
            }
            else
            {
                Niva = "nivå 4: över 199 artiklar";
                Niva4Count++;
            }

            

            tbxResultat.Text = ("Namn \t Persnr \t Distrikt \t Sålda artiklar\r\n");

            if (sp.Sold < 50)
            {
                tbxResultat.AppendText(sp.ToString() +"\r\n");
                   tbxResultat.AppendText (Niva1Count + " säljare har nått " + Niva + "\r\n");
            }
```

Comment: Please change your question to include a [mcve] - currently there's well over 100 lines of code, much of which appears to be irrelevant to the question. Additionally, use the preview to make sure that your code is formatted appropriately - a lot of it isn't at the moment.

Comment: Fundamentally though, you're trying to call a method with a parameter of type `int[]`, but you're providing an argument of type `List<Salesperson>`. That's never going to compile.

Comment: `void Bubbelsortera(int[] Salespeople)` -> `void Bubbelsortera(List<int> Salespeople)`. Inside `Bubbelsortera()` change all occurrences of `.Length` to `.Count`.

Comment: FYI, not related to your question, but you have redundent checks in your `Niva` field. After checking `if (Sold < 50)`, you don't need to include `Sold >= 50` in the following `else if` condition, since the first condition already determined that that will evaluate to `true`. It could be simplified to: `public int Niva() { return Sold < 50 ? 1 : Sold < 100 ? 2 : Sold < 200 ? 3: 4; }`

Comment: You should only ask one question per SO question, so you should ask a separate question on SO for the string formatting issue.

Comment: For the output question, move this line `tbxResultat.Text = ("Namn \t Persnr \t Distrikt \t Sålda artiklar\r\n");` to ABOVE the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You defined the bubble sort method to receive an `int[]` argument instead of a `List<Salesperson>`. Since you want to pass a `List<Salesperson>`, you need to modify the method to receive one.

It's not clear to me if you want to sort by the `Niva` field or the `Sold` field, but you can change that easily in the sample below (which uses `Sold`):

```
void BubbelSort(List<Salesperson> salespeople)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < salespeople.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < salespeople.Count - 1 - i; j++)
        {
            if (salespeople[j].Sold > salespeople[j + 1].Sold)
            {
                Salesperson temp = salespeople[j + 1];
                salespeople[j + 1] = salespeople[j];
                salespeople[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you also know how I get the result to show all my sellers that I have registered? I only get one seller that shows and I like the text "XX sellers have reached level 2" to appear after each level and not after each seller but I don't get it right.

Comment: As I said in a comment above, you should ask a separate question for that. But you can get the number like: `int level2People = salespeople.Count(s => s.Niva == 2);`

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark it as answered. Thanks!